# How to do a where clause with "not in" and a subquery with active record

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, arel

How can I write a subquery like this with activerecord (ruby on rails):

```
SELECT id, unit_cdl_required, load_group_id
FROM loads lo
WHERE unit_cdl_required=FALSE AND
load_group_id NOT IN (
  SELECT load_group_id
  FROM loads
  WHERE unit_cdl_required=TRUE
  AND load_group_id=lo.load_group_id
);
```

I tried:

```
Load.where("unit_cdl_required=FALSE AND load_group_id NOT IN (SELECT load_group_id FROM loads WHERE unit_cdl_required=TRUE AND load_group_id=lo.load_group_id)")
```

but got `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "lo"`

My schema is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV8U6.jpg

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps use the `lo` alias for the table in your nested query, i.e.: `Load.where("unit_cdl_required=FALSE AND load_group_id NOT IN (SELECT load_group_id FROM loads lo WHERE unit_cdl_required=TRUE AND load_group_id=lo.load_group_id)")`

Comment: lo alias *is* being used in the where() query

Comment: I am not sure how ruby works.. But that statement using only where condition. So you can't do `subquery` with join.. Because `lo` is unknown to your where..

Comment: I know that you are _referencing_ the `lo` alias in your `where` query, but where is this alias being defined? (Hence my suggestion above).

Comment: guys please ignore the "I tried:" section of my question. I only provide that because stack overflow prefers when there's evidence that we tried.  What I would love is a solution to the problem described. not a tweak of my answer. You have the schema info. let's stop bad mouthing my solution, because we know it doesn't work already

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange built sql query, maybe you wanted to do something like this:

```
SELECT id, unit_cdl_required, load_group_id FROM loads
LEFT JOIN loads AS required_loads ON required_loads.unit_cdl_required = TRUE
                AND required_loads.load_group_id = loads.load_group_id
WHERE loads.unit_cdl_required = TRUE AND required_loads.id IS NULL
```

then we will get something like this on the rails:

```
Load.join(
  "LEFT JOIN loads AS required_loads ON required_loads.unit_cdl_required = TRUE AND required_loads.load_group_id = loads.load_group_id"
).where('loads.unit_cdl_required = FALSE AND required_loads.id IS NULL')
```

There is a more beautiful solution

```
Load.where(unit_cdl_required: false)
    .where.not(
      load_group_id: Load.where(unit_cdl_required: true).pluck(:load_group_id)
    )
```